# Does Python's distutils set include paths for frameworks (osx) when compiling extensions?

Tags: python, distutils, macos-sierra

I've been working on an extension module for Python but in OSX Sierra it no longer finds headers belonging to the frameworks I'm linking to. It always found them before without any special effort. Has something changed lately regarding include paths in this tool chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to pass `cc -F /Library/Frameworks` for clang 7.2.0 and 8.0.0. Then it can find the headers.